# Send and receive SocketIO events concurrently in Python

Tags: python, socket.io

I'm setting up a terminal application in Python which communicates with a server via SocketIO. I would like it to do two things:

1. Wait for user input, and send a message to the server when it's received
2. Wait for server messages, and print them when they are received

I have #1 working already. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
sio = socketio.Client()
@sio.event
def send_message(data):
    sio.emit('send_message', {'data': data})

while True:
    i = input()
    message(i)
```

I also independently have #2 working already:

```
sio = socketio.Client()
@sio.event
def recv_message(data):
    print(data)

sio.wait()
```

My problem is that I don't know how to get #1 and #2 working concurrently. Either my program is waiting for user input, or it's waiting for server events. I think I need to make the listeners asynchronous, but I'm not sure how.